# how to disable particular js file in only particular view yii2

Tags: yii2-advanced-app

i doing ajax call and render view page in modal popup. but in this view page all js and css files are included. so in main page and ajax view page, js file got conflict.

i know how to disable js file in view page in yii-1.00

like this one

```
Yii::$app()->clientScript->scriptMap['jquery.js'] = false;
Yii::$app()->clientScript->scriptMap['yii.js'] = false;
```

but i dont know how to do this is in yii2.

so how can i do this.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

This will disable bundle which conflicts others.

Write below code in particular page in where you want to disable the JS files.

```
unset($this->assetBundles['yii\bootstrap\BootstrapAsset']);
unset($this->assetBundles['yii\web\JqueryAsset']);
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to exclude the assets which are registered on the layouts 
you can use return `$this->renderPartial("view");` from your controller 
action.

[render partial](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-controller.html#renderPartial%28%29-detail)

otherwise if your view contain other Javascripts/css files you want to inject  into the rendering result you may use `return $this->renderAjax("view")` instead

[render ajax](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-controller.html#renderAjax%28%29-detail)

Comment: thanks Nader, i already try this. but due to ajax call, some jquery render two times, so i want to just disable that repeat one.

Answer (score 0):

for Yii2
//in controller you can use this line...It will not reload assets with renderAjax.

```
\Yii::$app->assetManager->bundles = false;
```